# One SQL to summarize different 'group by' levels

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a Stock table in database:

[image]

Based on data in Stock Table, I want to have as output more detailed data:

[image]

Stock Qty represents the total qty in stock for Item A.

Location Qty represents the total qty for Item A for each Location

Sub Location Qty represents the total qty for Item A, for a specific location for each sub Location.

I was wondering if there is a way to get the detailed output in one query or should I make each query individually and write some code to join between each results.

**I could write:**

- In order to get Stock Qty:

  ```
  SELECT Item, Sum(Qty) as StockQty
  From Stock
  Group By Item;
  ```
- In order to get Location Qty:

  ```
  SELECT Item, Location, Sum(Qty) as LocationQty
  From Stock
  Group By Item, Location;
  ```
- In order to get Sub Location Qty:

  ```
  SELECT Item, Location, SubLocation, Sum(Qty) as SubLocationQty
  From Stock
  Group By Item, Location, SubLocation;
  ```

And then in code behind, write some code for output in a datagridview.

Actually, I am looking for a query that returns all the data in one datatable and bind it to the datagridview.

Any other solution is welcome.

I am working in AS400 but if there is a solution in others DBMS, please answered, I will try to make it work (if possible) in my DBMS environment.

Comment: Tag dbms used, the answer may depend on it.

Comment: I tagged ibm-midrange for AS400.

Comment: @jarlh, updated thank you

Comment: If you want the exact results shown in your example, use Giorgos Betos answer.  But assuming you're on a supported release (6.1+) of IBM i.  Then Zahiro's answer showing the use of `ROLLUP` is a "better" choice.

Comment: @CHarles , thank you. I am trying what they suggest. I just start with Zahiro solution but I am getting message that "ROLLUP in *LIBL type *N not found." I presume you just answered the question why the error is coming up. But if I am looking on Navigator version, I have 7.1.0

Comment: Navigator version doesn't matter.  You need to see what version of IBM i you have.  If you have access to a command line, DSPSFWRSC will show you.

Comment: Could it be i5/OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT t3.Item, t3.StockQty,
       t2.Location, t2.LocationQty,
       t1.SubLocation, t1.SubLocationQty
FROM (
   SELECT Item, Location, SubLocation, Sum(Qty) as SubLocationQty
   From Stock
   Group By Item, Location, SubLocation) AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT Item, Location, Sum(Qty) as LocationQty
   From Stock
   Group By Item, Location
) AS t2 ON t1.Item = t2.Item AND t1.Location = t2.Location
JOIN (
   SELECT Item, Sum(Qty) as StockQty
   From Stock
   Group By Item
) AS t3 ON t1.Item = t3.Item
```

Comment: thank you, just finish to test it, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

how about :

```
SELECT Item, Location, SubLocation, Sum(Qty) as SubLocationQty 
From Stock 
Group By Item, Location, SubLocation with rollup
```

if you have rollup in your rdbms it is really simple. just replace the 'null' you get with the string 'Total' and you're homefree.....

Comment: You might consider showing what the results set would be.  Since it's a bit different than the example the OP requested.  I think it's a better choice, but the OP might not.  `ROLLUP` is available in currently supported release of DB2 for IBM i.

Comment: Agreed. Had the OP provide us with a workable example. I can provide something of course but dunno if it of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple sub queries for this.

```
SELECT Item, 
(SELECT StockQty 
 FROM (SELECT Item, Sum(Qty) AS StockQty
       FROM Stock
       GROUP BY Item)) AS StockQty
(SELECT LocationQty 
 FROM (SELECT Item, Location, Sum(Qty) AS LocationQty
       FROM Stock
       GROUP BY Item, Location)) AS LocationQty,
(SELECT SubLocationQty 
 FROM (SELECT Item, Location, SubLocation, Sum(Qty) AS SubLocationQty
       FROM Stock
       GROUP BY Item, Location, SubLocation)) AS SubLocationQty
FROM Stock
```

Comment: You need correlated sub-queries, without group by.